# Creating a repository instance in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm new to Spring Data and to Spring in general, so don't be hard on me.

I can't find a way to instantiate a repository. I read the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-solr/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.create-instances

It describes different ways of declaring repositories (xml, filters, etc), but doesn't say how I can get an instance of it in my code.

Here is my configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <solr:repositories base-package="spring" />
    <solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://localhost:8983/solr" />

    <bean id="taskRepo" class="spring.SolrTaskRepository">
    </bean>

    <bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="solrServer"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And SolrTaskRepository:

```
public interface SolrTaskRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SolrCrudRepository<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findByOrigin(String origin, Pageable page);
}
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the repo(or any spring bean) somewhere out of the context:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContext.xml");

MyRepo obj = (MyRepo) context.getBean("myRepo");
```

If you use the repo in some other bean managed by spring(some service) you can autowire it

```
@Autowire
private MyRepo myRepo;// + setter
```

or inject it in the context:

```
<bean id="someService" class="com.org.core.SomeService">
        <property name="myRepo" ref="myRepo" />
</bean>
```

For both ways you need the bean defined in the context:

```
 <bean id="myRepo" class="com.org.core.MyRepo">
 </bean>
```

Example context file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myRepo" class="com.org.core.MyRepo">
     </bean>

</beans>
```

IF you load the context with `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` you need the file in the classpath.

Comment: Can I use it in JavaSE or do I have to use EE?

Comment: thanks, could you also give an example of applicationContext.xml file please?

Comment: I updated the answer. Also take a look at the http://www.mkyong.com/ (tutorials under Spring tab).

Comment: I also updated my question. I almost got it, but now I get a runtime exception, saying `Could not instantiate bean class [spring.SolrTaskRepository]: Specified class is an interface`. This is correct, because it's an interface, specifying additional methods, that Spring should generate for me. Do you know how I can say Spring to generate an instance from the specified interface?

Comment: Interfaces can't be instantated. You can instantate the class that implement the interface.

Comment: For example 'MyRepo implements SolrTaskRepository', and then '<bean id="myRepo" class="com.org.core.MyRepo"/>'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41876/discussion-between-damluar-and-evgeny)